# Cannot access drive mounted by sshfs using Ubuntu file manager

Tags: command-line, mount, permissions, sshfs

I've run into a problem with `sshfs` that I haven't seen before.

I mount serverB to serverA by doing the following (while logged in as root on serverA):

```
mkdir serverBLink
sshfs root@serverB:/ /home/myname/Documents/serverBLink
```

Once I do that, from the commandline I'm able to see all the files on serverB via the serverBLink folder. 
Business as usual.

However, I cannot access the serverBLink folder using File Manager on Ubuntu.  I don't know why.  I thought it might be a permissions thing because I'm technically signed into the computer as "dot" but in the commandline, I've switched to root... ??

As a test I tried running `chmod 777` on the serverBLink folder to grant everyone access to everything inside but it still doesn't work.

Using File Manager, when I try to access the serverBLink folder, I get the error message:

> Could not enter folder

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe try `-o allow_other` to [allow users other than the mounter to access](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=FAQ#Why_don.27t_other_users_have_access_to_the_mounted_filesystem.3F).

Even better, you don't need to be `root` to use `sshfs`, so you can simply create the directory and mount the remote directory as yourself (but with `root@serverB`).

From a security perspective, you need to establish a connection as `root@serverB` (which you do already), and then you need at least execute permission on the mount directory and access to the mount contents itself.

Comment: I tried to use that switch.  but i'm getting the error:fusermount: failed to open /etc/fuse.conf: Permission denied
fusermount: option allow_other only allowed if 'user_allow_other' is set in /etc/fuse.conf.  So i uncommented the user_allow_other line in the conf file but that still doesnt work

Comment: Just mount as yourself then. It seems to be a default (and sensible) restriction.

Comment: that worked.  i removed the directory.  recreated as myself.  mounted as myself.  works fine now.  thanks